# Supporting multiple versions of Dagger in a project

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, dagger-2

I am working on a project A and it has component B which is dependent on version 1.2.1 of dagger. Now, I am trying to add a library C to the project which depends on version 2.4 of dagger. Is there a way, where I can have both B and C in A without having to either upgrading B to 2.4?

Comment: can you update  your question with build.gradle file?

Comment: Why is B a component and C a module? Is there a difference? If they are both child projects of A, then sure, you can do what you want. Each project can defined its own dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, C actually is a library but I guess we can take it as a module.